# Gem::InstallError: gem-wrappers is not installed in GEM_HOME during gem cleanup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

How do I avoid gem cleanup specific errors. I see the following error while performing gem cleanup. Gem::InstallError: gem-wrappers is not installed in GEM_HOME

```
gem cleanup
Cleaning up installed gems...
Attempting to uninstall gem-wrappers-1.2.4
Unable to uninstall gem-wrappers-1.2.4:
    Gem::InstallError: gem-wrappers is not installed in GEM_HOME, try:
    gem uninstall -i /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global gem-wrappers
Attempting to uninstall gem-wrappers-1.2.4
Unable to uninstall gem-wrappers-1.2.4:
    Gem::InstallError: gem-wrappers is not installed in GEM_HOME, try:
    gem uninstall -i /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global gem-wrappers
Clean Up Complete
```

Comment: so did you try manually remove gem uninstall gemwrappers as follows: `-i /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global gem-wrappers`?

Comment: I get the same error - the suggested manual uninstall works but `gem cleanup` doesn't. GEM_HOME matches `gem environment gemdir` exactly. If gem can suggest a command that works, why doesn't cleanup just do it for me?

Comment: Just in case it's useful to someone else, this command ran the uninstall for me on the 20 plus gems that `gem cleanup` failed to deal with automatically =)   `$(gem cleanup 2>&1 | grep "gem uninstall")`

Answer (score 1):

The cleanup command removes old versions of gems from GEM_HOME that are not required to meet a dependency. If a gem is installed elsewhere in GEM_PATH the cleanup command won’t delete it.

You can try using `sudo gem cleanup`

Reference [gem cleanup](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-cleanup)

Another [Cleanup gems](http://nathanhoad.net/how-to-clean-up-old-gems)

Comment: I am facing a specific problem, how do I resolve? The above is not useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

add below one line on your shell rc file. (like, .bashrc, .zshrc, .profile)

```
export GEM_HOME=$(/usr/local/bin/gem environment gemdir)
```